# retrieve bson.Binary with completed Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, go, binary, bson

I'm using MongoDB for my Go and Rails projects (using same database) and i have a bson.Binary data in my document (contain Base64 encoded publicKey)

```
type Device struct {
  Id            string          `json:"id" form:"id" bson:"_id"`
  PublicKey     bson.Binary     `json:"pub_key" form:"pub_key" bson:"public_key"`
  Token         string          `json:"token" form:"token" bson:"token"`
  CreatedAt     time.Time       `json:"created_at" bson:"created_at"`
  UpdatedAt     time.Time       `json:"updated_at" bson:"updated_at"`
}
```

but when i retrieve it in my Go projects and the data is somehow corrupted (4 characters are missing)

```
device := models.Device{}
err = db.C(models.CollectionDevice).Find(bson.M{"_id": deviceId}).One(&device)

publicKey := device.PublicKey
publicKeyBase64 := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(publicKey.Data)
fmt.Println("publicKey BinaryData: ", publicKey.Data)
```

t

```
"pub_key": {
        "Kind": 0,
        "Data": "Axj5A9BgkKJohGh/0BAQEFAAMBjYAAMYmCAYGACqW0smeNiaIgRgXJv7dLZ0n5gTeXxiI9q6h8EdbiPDLiFsv7Jgatwxm+OpucrUBp4sZp/othrSQWnJQR5vpnCZYZnNJUdjTAYw+PyjQ2qq9YEeLHMnMzhYgaq2ata+CSsCjalkOyzLt/rDEBn5WHaCfYm0Vm+QbbEWVLltUqcjvScOyAwEAAQn"
}
```

(220 characters length in Data)

the original Base64 encoded string is

Axj5A9BgkKJohGh/0BAQEFAAMBjYAAMYmCAYGACqW0smeNiaIgRgXJv7dLZ0\n5gTeXxiI9q6h8EdbiPDLiFsv7Jgatwxm+OpucrUBp4sZp/othrSQWnJQR5vp\nCZYZnNJUdjTAYw+PyjQ2qq9YEeLHMnMzhYgaq2ata+CSsCjalkOyzLt/rDEB\n5WHaCfYm0Vm+QbbEWVLltUqcjvScOyAwEAAQ\n

with 224 characters

i use this code in my Go projects:

```
fmt.Println("publicKey: ", publicKey.Data)
//publicKey is bson.Binary data type
```

i have tried to retrieve the data from my rails projects (same database) and it retrieve correctly

```
public_key.as_json["$binary"]
```

the result is exactly right (224 characters) :

```
"Axj5A9BgkKJohGh/0BAQEFAAMBjYAAMYmCAYGACqW0smeNiaIgRgXJv7dLZ0\nn5gTeXxiI9q6h8EdbiPDLiFsv7Jgatwxm+OpucrUBp4sZp/othrSQWnJQR5v\npnCZYZnNJUdjTAYw+PyjQ2qq9YEeLHMnMzhYgaq2ata+CSsCjalkOyzLt/rD\nEBn5WHaCfYm0Vm+QbbEWVLltUqcjvScOyAwEAAQn\n"
```

As you can see, there is still a \n at the last of string. Any one know why 4 characters are missing in Go ?

===== Additional information =====

When i store it in my mongoDB from my Rails API, i receive public_key params as Base64 format, but i decode it to binary and then i stored it with this code

```
def create
  params = device_params      
  public_key = Base64.decode64 device_params[:public_key]
  params[:public_key] = BSON::Binary.new(public_key, :generic)
  device = Device.find_or_create_by(id: device_params[:id])

  render_success device.update_attributes(params), device
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original data contains exactly 4 newline characters `\n`:

```
Axj5A9BgkKJohGh/0BAQEFAAMBjYAAMYmCAYGACqW0smeNiaIgRgXJv7dLZ0\n
5gTeXxiI9q6h8EdbiPDLiFsv7Jgatwxm+OpucrUBp4sZp/othrSQWnJQR5vp\n
CZYZnNJUdjTAYw+PyjQ2qq9YEeLHMnMzhYgaq2ata+CSsCjalkOyzLt/rDEB\n
5WHaCfYm0Vm+QbbEWVLltUqcjvScOyAwEAAQ\n
```

These newline characters are not part of the Base64 encoded data, they are just to format the input.

Problem arises likely when you try to store this as a raw string literal, because this is an interpreted string literal, the `\n` sequences are to be discarded / removed.

Since the backslash is an invalid symbol for "normal" Base64, they are removed, though the subsequent `n` is not (because `n` is valid in Base64). As a result, you get corrupted Base64 data.

You should either completely remove the line endings and then you get a valid Base64 which you may store either as a string or binary; or store it as a general string which will preserve the line endings (which have to be dealt with during base64 decoding).

Comment: When i store it in my mongoDB from my Rails API, i receive public_key params as Base64 format, but i decode it to binary and then i stored it with this code 

      `BSON::Binary.new(public_key, :generic)`

Comment: @calvinsugianto Then maybe your decoding code has some errors.

Comment: i think my decoding doesn't have some errors, because when i retrieve my data in Rails, i get 100% exactly matched Base64 that i sent before.

Comment: @calvinsugianto That's not very convincing. If you want help, please post more of your code. Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: @calvinsugianto I'm interested more in how you save these values to MongoDB using Go, not how you load them; because the public key Base64 in MongoDB already seems to be corrupt.

Comment: actually, i don't save it using Go, I save it from my Rails project and when i retrieve it in rails from Database, it is still fine and there isn't any corruption

Comment: So we can safely assume that rails ignores the newlines, no?

Comment: @calvinsugianto Please execute a query (filtered by `_id`) in your MongoDB console, and post the document you see there.